How to capture signal sent to browser by CMD + click on trackpad?
I posted a similar question on Apple's "Community" website, but this question is more focused: Is there a way of finding out what signal is sent to the browser when CMD + click is used on a trackpad?
The reason for the question is that I'm encountering websites that interpret the event differently; namely, in some cases it produces a new tab with the page linked to, but in others, it navigates directly to the page, instead. This is relatively new behavior, so I'm trying to figure out whether the signal sent by my Mac changed with a recent update, or whether the server-side javascript is misidentifying the signal. (Note for a given site, the behaviors on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox agree.)
Thanks.
